# How to find the source of the XapleParseException

Tags: wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary, xamlparseexception

I am working on a very complex WPF application. I am getting the following exception and I am having a hard time figuring our where is the problematic resource.:
[image]

Any advice as to what is the most effective wat to investigate?

Comment: You've got a borderbrush set to something isn't valid. It could be from a dependency property defined in your code which has no initial default value. And the error comes from the point when the ui is being built. Generally speaking. Write a bit of code or markup at a time and prove it works as early as possible. If that is not practical because of your app's architecture then you should probably reconsider the architecture. If that is not practical then write new stuff in a dev/test stub to prove as much as you can.  Then add to the main thing. But again. Smallest iterations possible.

Comment: @Andy Hey. Its a huge application with a very and unnecessary complex architecture. And It was not written by me... The safest way to go is to change all the borderbrush that point to a staticresource to a static value and see which one is the culprit. I was wandering whether there is a better way